# Android market application device's country issue

Tags: android, google-play

My application is released for US and brazil, I use my gmail account for downloading which is india based.

I have release my application on android market, **i can see the application through browser, but not from mobile.**

When i try to download an application from browser, it gives me **"This item cannot be installed on your device's country android"**

Does it mean, application released for specific country, only those can see app and download? others cannot see application on android market?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, if you release only for specific countries, the others shouldn't be able to download the apk.

Comment: Yes, true others are not able to view/download apk from android market, but browser shows app, at time of downloading it gives me the above error.. which means it detects network carrier of country first.

Answer (score 1):

You have marked the application for use in the US and Brazil. Your account and thus phone's Market app are associated to India. So, you have told Market to not let phones/accounts like yours use the app. Yes, you would have to mark the application as available to India too in order to use it on your account/phone.

Comment: so should i create a google account with US/Brazil country ?? and then try it

Comment: No. You should make your app available to India.

Comment: content to display in app, is not related to india.. so i cannot

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not the case. would you please check your device OS version & the target

version build which you submitted to Android Market.

I think that is the problem. Check it & try again.

Best Regards,

~Anup

Comment: released with `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />` ie. for android 2.1 and my devices is also 2.1 compatible

Comment: No but what is the targetSdkVersion for your application.

Comment: i think targetSdkVersion is not mandatory to declare, only minSdkVersion identifies on which android devices is necessary. for reference here is link [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html]

Comment: No I just wanted to know, at the time of creation of your application which sdk version you had selected.

Comment: Android 2.1, declared in manifest and default.properties too

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question, while uploading app in android market, application is selected under brazil market only, and yes only people of brazil are able to view and download. If application searched on android market via browser, than i can see my app on android market, while downloading it from browser, it gives **me "This item cannot be installed on your device's country"**. which means before downloading android market detects on which device application is going to get installed which depends upon on google account and device's network carrier.

Found a [link for same](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html)